# How to change the output of a dense layer in a keras model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Given the following [model](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/):

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_91 (InputLayer)        [(None, 25)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
token_and_position_embedding (None, 25, 400)           5938800   
_________________________________________________________________
transformer_block_97 (Transf (None, 25, 400)           74832    
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_82  (None, 400)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_337 (Dropout)        (None, 400)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_339 (Dense)            (None, 25)                22575     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_338 (Dropout)        (None, 25)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_340 (Dense)            (None, 25)                570      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,709,907
Trainable params: 3,709,907
Non-trainable params: 0
```

In keras, how to change the output layer to `(None, 25, 7)` dimension? This is the current model configuration:

```
embed_dim = 400  # Embedding size for each token
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
ff_dim = 32  # Hidden layer size in feed forward network inside transformer

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(25,))


embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
X = embedding_layer(inputs)
transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
X = transformer_block(X)
X = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(X)
X = layers.Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(X)
X= layers.Dropout(0.1)(X)

outputs = layers.Dense(25, activation="softmax")(x)
```

Comment: Why 25 x 7? which does each number represent?

Comment: @DavidKaftanit is just an hypothetical example. I would like to know how to reshape the output in general (if possible)

Comment: You're doing more than reshaping. You're changing the number of elements from 25 to `25 x 7`. Are you thinking you just want to duplicate the 25 element layer 7 times? Or was there a typo and you meant "reshape to (None, 5, 5)"?

Comment: Yes it was a typo I meant to say `(None, 5, 5)`. Any idea of how to do that? I tried modifying the input however, my model doesnt not work when I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `tf.keras.layers.Reshape`. Per our discussion in the comments, see how to reshape a layer from `(None, 25)` to `(None, 5, 5)`.

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input((25))                                                                                   
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense((25))(inp)                                                                            
reshaped = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5,5))(layer)                                                                    
model = tf.keras.Model(inp, reshaped)
```

`model.summary()` yields

```
_________________________________________________________________                                                       
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #                                                          
=================================================================                                                       
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 25)]              0                                                                
_________________________________________________________________                                                       
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 25)                650                                                              
_________________________________________________________________                                                       
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 5, 5)              0                                                                
=================================================================                                                       
Total params: 650                                                                                                       
Trainable params: 650                                                                                                   
Non-trainable params: 0
```

EDIT:

To clarify how you would implement this into your code, add the following after `outputs = layers.Dense(25, activation="softmax")(x)`

```
reshaped_outputs = layers.Reshape((5,5))(outputs)
```

Comment: Why the `transformer_block_104` dissapeared?

Comment: I couldn't use that in my example since you didn't show where it came from in yours. I'll edit the answer to more clearly show how to implement in your code.